# Handlebars templates: top level data disappears in #each?

Tags: jquery, foreach, iteration, handlebars.js

Why the top level object data disappears in handblebars' `#each`? For instance,

jquery + handlebars,

```
$(this).html(Handlebars.getTemplate('summary')({
     base_url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/", // what I mean by the top level data
     types:  {
        page: {...},
        post: {...}
     }
}));
```

handblebars templates,

```
{{ base_url }} // I get http://www.mywebsite.com/

{{#each types}}

{{ base_url }} // I get nothing

{{/each}}
```

So how can I retain the top level data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reach the scope outside of the `each` iteration by using

`{{../base_url}}`

Sorry if the formatting is sloppy, I typed this on a phone.